# When reimplementing Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.dropRow(), how do I access classes of would-be parent?

Tags: javascript, theming

Using code below, I can access classes of a row that's being dropped:

```
Drupal.tableDrag.prototype._dropRow = Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.dropRow;
Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.dropRow = function(event, self) {
  console.log('dropRow');
  console.log("feature-group: " + $(self.rowObject.element).hasClass('feature-group'));
  console.log("feature: " + $(self.rowObject.element).hasClass('feature'));
  if ( /* use classes here */ ) {
    /* return custom result here */
  }
  /* fallback to default here */
  return self._dropRow(event, self);
};
```

But now I don't want to test classes of a dragged row, but ones of a row that would be a parent. How do I do that?

To clarify: I need tabledrag parent, not DOM parent. All tabledrag rows are DOM siblings, and I need the row with ID field value equal to the would-be Parent ID field value (`class="parent"`) of a dragged row.

Something in JavaScript sets the parent ID properly, during either drag or drop (can't tell), so I'm sure there is a way. I just don't know how to find it.

Comment: Interesting that this is accumulating downvotes, seems like a good Drupal JS question to me...@downvoters any chance you could comment on the specific objections?

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference to some parent DOM element ... the jquery [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) or [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) function(s) comes to mind. Then use `hasClass` on those parents as needed.

some parent would be something like the following based on your example:

```
var parents = $(self.rowObject.element).parents(/* a selector to limit the type of parent, td, tr, whatever */);
```

**EDIT:**

dragged rows get a class of like `.dragged-previous`. The file `tabledrag.js` doesnt care about the current row, nor about IDs of anything during drag -- its just doing a DOM swap of rows and inserting the dragged row before another row; and assigning a Drupal `weight` to the hidden weight column. So cant you use like [jquery prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) function to get the immediate previous element:

```
var parent = $('#menu-overview tr.drag-previous').prev();
```

I'm taking these values from a Main Menu tabledrag example of a vanilla D7 site:
[image]

Comment: I meant tabledrag parent, not DOM parent. All tabledrag rows are siblings, and I want the row with ID equal to the would-be Parent ID of a dragged row.